# ffprobe - shuffled frame metadata

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, ffprobe, mkv, pyav

I'm using `mkvmerge` to combine a mp4 CFR video with a text file containing VFR timestamps. The command used was

```bash
mkvmerge --timestamps 0:timestamps.txt input_video.mp4 -o output_video.mkv
```

Where the textfile `timestamps.txt` was of a v2 timestamp format. Here are the first few entries

```
# timecode format v2
0
6
21
36
53
71
87
103
123
```

I'm trying to print these timestamps back out with

```bash
ffprobe -v 0 -show_entries packet=pts,duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -select_streams v output_video.mkv
```

But I receive shuffled entries

```
0|6
6|15
21|15
36|17
53|18
123|15
87|16
71|16
103|20
```

If I read the frames with `PyAV` for example, I get the values in correct order.

```python
import av
c = av.open("output_video.mkv")
for frame in c.decode(video=0):
     print(frame.pts)
```

Output:

```
0
6
21
36
53
71
87
103
123
```

Am I using ffprobe incorrectly? Any help would be very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the video stream has B-frames then future P-frames which act as reference for B-frames are encoded first and stored in that order. They are reordered after decoding.

For ffprobe, the entries in `packet` are arranged in decode or storage order. In `frames`, they are decoded and arranged in presentation order.